# 'I liked them' 'i like them' do they pronounced the same way?

Tags: pronunciation

> 'I **liked** them.' vs 'i **like** them.'

are they pronounced the same way?

And

> 'I **learnt** them.' vs 'I **learn** them.'

Do you pronounce the 't' at the end of learnt?

If no, are they pronounced same?

Comment: This gets into the area of dialects and English vernaculars as well as the way individual speakers enunciate. In both received pronunciation and North American English vernaculars, you pronounce the '-ed' in liked and the '-t' in learnt. However, depending on the speaker's enunciation, you may or may not be able to hear them distinctly, especially before the dental fricative ("th" in them).

Answer (score 1):

The D at the end of liked is pronounced. But it's pronounced as a T.

Usually if a word ends with the letter T, the T is not fully pronounced. It's not wrong to fully pronounce the T, but usually Americans and Canadians don't.

Instead, the sound that comes before the T is cut short; in the word "short," the "or" sound is very short. In "can't," the an is very short; the N is almost not even pronounced. For most words it's helpful to stop the sound and end the word by sticking your tongue against the roof of your mouth, as if you're going to say the T.

[This is called the stop T.](https://jonathansamericanenglish.com/2017/12/03/can-or-cant/)